# MapQuest Driving Directions API

Tags: mapquest

Could anyone explain me what is "leg" and "maneuver" in a route and how to show the route highlight with this new API? Earlier with MapQuest 5.x we used to do it with LinePrimitive Class in MQClientInterface.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do? Are you using the JavaScript Maps API (for instance) to show the route on a map?  If so, the JavaScript Maps API (and Flash Maps API) have convenience functions for showing a route on the map and they handle most of the heavy lifting for you, so you don't have to call the Directions API directly if you want to show the route on a map generated by the JavaScript Maps API or Flash Maps API.

A "leg" is essentially a stop along a route -- for instance if you want to route yourself from Lancaster, PA to Harrisburg, PA to York, PA -- Lancaster to Harrisburg is one leg, while Harrisburg to York is another.

A "maneuver" is almost like each turn you would have to make, so the turn-by-turn directions included with each leg.

Hope this helps!